# How to set the width of an element equal to device-width?

Tags: html, css

I want the header of my website to take as much width as the monitor's screen. I've tried giving `width: 100%`, `width: vw` and `width: device-width`. The problem with all these is that when I resize the browser window the header takes width equal to that of *current viewport* not the *device-width*. The code is as following:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: courier;
  color: white;
}
header {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: device-width;
  background-color: #666633;
  text-align: center;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="heading"> Syco Scientist Records </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="anupamindex.html" class="active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ourwork.html">Our Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

As you can see when the browser window is resized there is no option to scroll. Had I given the width in pixels then the navigation bar wouldn't collapse and could be seen when scrolled to right.

> - How do set the width of header same as monitor screen width even when the browser window is resized?

Only way I think this is possible is to use `@media` media queries which set different width for header as per the monitor width.

> - Is there any analogous of `device-width` for non-mobile platforms?

Comment: Are you try using bootstrap?

Comment: @haithamsha No, I am not using Bootstrap.

Comment: vw is "viewport width". Do you want to compute beyond the browser bounds or .... 100vw is literally 100% of viewport width. Can't get much wider.

Comment: @Phix That's the problem. 100vw is actually no different from 100% for html and body tags. I want something equivalent to `device-width` that work for non-mobile platforms.

Comment: You have a plnkr or fiddle? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Phix Do you want this https://jsfiddle.net/0to3tudh/ Decrease the width of the browser window you will see the problem.

Comment: So basically you want the width of the header to always be the width of the users screen so when they reduce the size it doesn't respond and isn't fluid? This would mean you get horizontal scrollbars?   May I ask why you want it to work that way? It might help solve your issue.

Comment: @Sephorra Because I already have made the responsive layout http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ . Now I want to make a static website. The problem is I don't want it to take a specific width in pixels(e.g. 800px) because on a different size monitor, say 1380px width, the website won't span to the whole width.

Comment: Okay, so css will work with the width of the viewport, but it wont give you the width of the users monitor so I've add a javascript option for you as an answer. However, i would always recommend having a fluid, responsive site over something that is fixed. Much better experience for the user :)

Comment: I can't understand why you need the screen width instead of the viewport width. The webpage is rendered inside the viewport, not the screen. However is easy to achieve with javascript: `document.getElementById('header').style=screen.width+'px';` in the DOMLoaded event.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the screen size not the browser width you will need javascript. You can use

```
screen.width
```

(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp)
Then you can use that to set the width of the container with javascript.

*Note: you may have some discrepancies between operating systems*

Answer (score 2):

you can manage screen size using javascript

check this example

```
<script>
var txt = "";
txt += "<p>Total width/height: " + screen.width + "*" + screen.height + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Available width/height: " + screen.availWidth + "*" + screen.availHeight + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Color depth: " + screen.colorDepth + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Color resolution: " + screen.pixelDepth + "</p>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `width: auto`. It will adjust your width according to the padding.

Answer (score 0):

please try this without using javascript

```
 div
    {
        width: 100vw; 
        height: 56.25vw; 
        background: pink;
        max-height: 100vh;
        max-width: 177.78vh; /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
        left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
    }
```

or

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta tag first for the hole html body then you can use with : 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I will use:

`width: 100vw;
display: inline-block;`

or I will trying with `display: flex;` Check you don't have anywhere (on parent) `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work without javascript, but it's only three lines... 
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yL3fbyf/

I get the screen width, put it in a variable and add 'px' to that number:

```
var x = screen.width + 'px';
```

Then I assign that variable as `width` to the header. I gave the header an ID since for some reason `getElementsByTagName("header")` didn't work:

```
var y = document.getElementById('my_header');
y.style.width = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

without jquery/javascript it may be hard to match up the width/height of an element you need. options are either setting 100% or hard coding upon the device screen width/height. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Relative values like vw(viewport width), vh(viewport height), vm(viewport minimum) are well suited for devices like screens, where the device size and resolution is not known or could change.

px,em & % are the values can be used for screen designs. Try different values and see.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can have an element occupy the entire screen size just using CSS. However, you can use javascript to circumvent this CSS limitation.

```
<script>
    //Here, "header" is the id assigned to the element you want to have this effect on
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    header.style.width = screen.width + "px"
    header.style.height = screen.height + "px"
</script>
```

You can either use height or width or use both for an element, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Add property `height: auto;` to header, as it will give your code the flexibility to adjust height according to the screen on which it is used. So, now u use any device, your header height will adjust automatically accordingly.

Comment: I downvoted because adding property `height: auto;` is redundant. Auto is the default value assigned to height property.